# Why is Laravel eloquent returning empty

Tags: laravel, eloquent

This is my model

```
namespace App\Models\Invitation;

use App\Models\Model;

class SendtoType extends Model
{
}
```

When i get data from SendtoType it return empty or null but i sure sendto_types table has datas

```
    $types = SendtoType::all();
    dd($types); // return empty collection

    $types = SendtoType::find(1); 
    dd($types);// null
```

It's happend after i run php artisan command:reset_table sendto_types command.

I cleared cache but it's not working.

Comment: whats your table name for SendtoType model?

Comment: try to declare  protected $table = 'your_table_name';  in your model SendtoType and check.

Comment: did you check that your table have some values?

Comment: @AmolRokade: my table`s name is sendto_types and i declare $table but it still not working

Comment: so try declaring the protected $table = 'sendto_types'; in model and check.

Comment: @NaveedAli yes i did

Comment: @AmolRokade : i tried but still not working

Comment: can you please show us your model code?

Comment: if you mean the code in model file so that i have not any code in it

Comment: Can you show screenshot of your database table?

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan i'm so sorry but i cant do that

Comment: @hayumi kuran why?

Answer (score 4):

Thank you everyone, i found my mistake:

i set timestamp for table's deleted_at column but forgot to set not null so it also filled deleted_at column when i add data.
That's why eloquent clause return empty.
So silly mistake!

Answer (score 0):

You can add `protected $table = 'sendto_types';` inside your model class with actual table name in your database.

```
class SendtoType extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'sendto_types';
}
```

Comment: please make sure your table name is `sendto_types` in your database. If not just replace the actual table name.

Comment: i sure the table is exist and has datas

Answer (score 0):

Command `command:reset_table` is not a built in command, so you'd need to look at your source code to see what it does, but by the name of it, I would assume the command empties your table.

In this case, your table is empty, so your query will not return any results.

Comment: yes this command delete current table and create the new one , and i have added data into table already